# onEdit function where action in specific column sets value for corresponding row in the next column over

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to work out a google scripts onEdit function that is only triggered by one specific column, and will set the value in the same row on the next column.

The script should set the value (new Date()) in column D when a cell in column C is edited, and should be limited to rows after row 7.

Currently I have one that kinda works, but it works when you edit any cell in the sheet, so it's not ideal. I've been googling and reading for a while to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
function onEdit() { //Function to add a time stamp to Complete Time Column D
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range= sheet.getActiveCell();
  var row = range.getRow();
  if(row>7){
    sheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue(new Date());
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You should take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) and use it to find
  the active sheet and active range.
- The following script will set a new date in column D when a cell in column C is edited, but after row 7.
- You are very close. In the same way you use `var row = range.getRow();` you can also use `var row = range.getColumn();` and put that as a constraint to be `3` (column C).
- The script will work for the active sheet. You might want to restrict this functionality to a particular sheet (e.g. `Sheet1`). If yes, then change the `if` condition to something like this:

  `if(as.getName() == 'Sheet1' && row>7 && col==3)`

---

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
    
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  if(row>7 && col==3){
    as.getRange(row, 4).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Marios. Unfortunately this isn't working at all. I get an error message: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 14, file "Data Sheet Date")

I had been trying to use the event object previously and ran into similar errors, btw

Comment: `onEdit` is **not** supposed to be executed manually by you. It is executed automatically when you edit a cell and hence the name `onEdit()`. Please click on save to save the code and `edit` a cell in column C after row 7 to see the result in column D. @AndrewHarrell

Comment: That's right, I remember reading that. I did test in the actual sheet after saving it and nothing happens though. @Marios

Comment: Please repeat all the steps again. **Clear** all the code you have in the script editor (hence remove the previous onEdit code). Copy the code snippet in my answer and paste it to a `blank` .gs file in script editor. Save the code, and go back to the sheet. **Edit** a cell in column C after row 7 to see the result in column D. @AndrewHarrell

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for you help. I am new to this, and previously had been able to just comment out the other lines and a new script would run. I'll keep this in mind in the future. Thanks again @Marios

Comment: @Cooper true, indeed.

Comment: Sorry I had an error in it. `function onEdit(e) { 
  if(e.range.rowStart>7 && e.range.columnStart==3){
    e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4).setValue(new Date());
  }
}`